# Date shows as a number (Excel)

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, format, numbers

When I try to combine text and date by for example `="4 cats were born in "&B6` where `B6 = 20.01.2020` i get

> 4 cats were born in 43850

instead of

> 4 cats were born in 20.01.2020

How can I change it to set date in proper format? When I change format of this cell to "Date" nothing happens. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
="4 cats were born in "&TEXT(B6,"mm.dd.yyyy")
```

Also, see [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/join-date-and-text) link.